# Unable to fetch RSS content using php

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to read a RSS feed using php. I developed this code which was working fine in a local XAMPP server but when I uploaded it to my webserver it is unable to fetch any content and doesn't generate any errors either.

```
<?php
try {
//Read the RSS content
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://properstatus.com/rss.php');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array(
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue
        );
array_push($feed, $item);
    }


    $limit = 6;
    $link = "http://bit.ly/1HmbPn4 ";
    for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $payload = $title . "..." . $link;
        echo "Desc: " . $description . "<br/>";        
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
    die();
}
?>
```

Can you spot anything wrong in the code? Or might it be a version conflict? The localhost runs php 5.5.15 the server runs php 5.5.20

P.S: The code is uploaded and can be tested live at http://tweet.unistarcrm.com/test.php

Comment: Doesn't `array_push($feed, $item);` belong inside the loop above it.

Comment: @JimGarrison yea, you are right, I seem to have made that mistake while formating the code, thanks will edit it.

Comment: Doesn't address the issue though @JimGarrison the page still loads empty, and I can't figure out just what might be the issue in here